# Webpage not displaying from the beginning of the page

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a webpage that doesn't load from the top of the page. When the webpage loads, it automatically goes to an image. I think I am experiencing this because of two issues.

1. I think it has something to do with the line

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate( {scrollTop: $( '#' + image_container.attr( 'id' ) ).offset().top }, 500 );
```

Can someone explain what it's doing? I'm not sure how the scrollTop is working in conjunction with animate and the offset() function.

2. While I was tracking down the line above, I experienced something strange with the following code.

```
#In file 1

console.log("1")
console.log(function1())
console.log("2)

#In file 2, this is where the line of code from the first part of my question resides

function1(){
   some_code_here;
   return true;
}
```

I wanted to see exactly what my question for part 1 was doing so I did a console.log before and after the function while also doing a console.log on the function itself. The console prints out `1` and `2` fine. However when it comes to `function1()` I get undefined. I was expecting `true`. I actually added the line `return true` myself to file 2 because it was giving me `undefined`. However by adding the return statement I still got undefined.

Since the google chrome inspector is telling me `undefined` instead of an error, I know that `function1()` has been accessed, but why is it not printing `true`?

Lastly, in an attempt to try and stop the webpage from displaying at where the image is (rather than at the beginning of the webpage), I tried `window.scrollTo(0,0)` in file 1 but that doesn't seem to work for me unless I comment out the call to `function1()`.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: The part 1 mean scroll to location of the image container with 500ms scroll animation if I not mistaken. Can you share you code how you included the javascript files? Please make sure the file2 must come before file1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem to 2 was because the chrome inspector wasn't updating the javascript that I was editing. I had to go `chrome inspector` then to the `Network` tab and check `Disable cache`.

You can check whether your javascript is being updated by going to the same `Network` tab and select the js file.

I also restarted the server after that but I think by disabling the cache would have done it.